# How do I get rid of the static linking error from QT?

Tags: qt, build, static

I wanted to link QT statically using this guide and have followed the steps to do so, however when I run the "qt-windows-static-build.ps1" I always get the error message at the end:

```
mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
Out-File : Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Qt\Static\6.1.3\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf" konnte nicht gefunden werden.
In C:\Qt\qt-windows10-static-build.ps1:167 Zeichen:6

- "@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii
- ```
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Looked but the file exists under the path.
Here are my customized lines:

```
param(
$QtSrcUrl = "https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.1/6.1.3/single/qt-everywhere-src-6.1.3.zip",
$QtStaticDir = "C:_QtStatic", # NO TRAILING SLASH
$QtVersion = "6.1.3", #If you change this, you'll need to change the URL above to download as well...
$MingwDir = "",
[switch]$NoPause = $false
```

)

What else could my errors be?

Answer (score 0):

The script is outdated, I've added a warning and - hopefully helpful - instructions to that page.

Please refer to the official documentation for instructions how to build Qt on Windows: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-building.html

Also, the rationale why to use a static build is questionable. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html for how to deploy a Qt application on Windows.

If you really want a static build, pass `-static` to `configure`.